# Problems with while in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, comparison

I am doing a bash script with the web api of checkpoint.

```
126: No such file or directory
```

this error refers to line 25 in which I have the next sentence:

```
while [$reglas < $n_reglas ];do
```

I have tried changing that to:

```
while [$reglas -lt $n_reglas ];do
```

but the error persist and I am not sure of what is the real problem.

The variables are defined like this:

```
reglas=1
n_reglas=$(echo $rulebase_list | jq '.total')
```

and I have printed their value in order to check that they are taking the correct value. Any idea of which is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO OP has to post samples of input and output in code tags along with that efforts that OP has put to solve his/her problem too in post, so kindly do so and let us know then. This is not clear.

Comment: Try `while [ $reglas -lt $n_reglas ]; do` (note the space after the opening bracket) or `while ((reglas < n_reglas)); do`.

Comment: Happy that the answer helped, what was the cause / what fixed it? Could you write a short comment to my answer? I might be able to update it to be more helpful for others comming along this road :)

Comment: the bug was that I was doing reglas=$reglas+1 and that make a string which was 1+1, so I use reglas=$(echo $((regkas+1))) as in the example of Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not very clear what the actual problem is. Please try to reproduce the problem in a small code snippet that we can execute and troubleshoot. This way we don't need to guess and can provide more precise help.

Here is a small snippet with a ton of assumptions.

```
reglas=1
n_reglas=4 # https://jqplay.org/s/BCTXyJ4NLc

while [ $reglas -lt $n_reglas ]; do
   echo $reglas
   reglas=$(($reglas+1))
done

# $bash -f main.sh
# 1
# 2
# 3
```